# Rhino mock questions

Tags: rhino-mocks

Simple Rhino mock questions.

- what's the difference between replay and replayAll?
- What's the difference between SetupResult.On(Of T).Call vs Expect.Call(Of T)?
- What's BackToRecord used for?

Answer (score 0):

Read The Manual(RTM): [Rhino Mocks documentation in this case](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx). It covers all of the above mentioned questions.